# Add a new template option to category block in CS-Cart

Tags: cs-cart

I have created a new template file for the category block in CS-Cart. How do I add this as one of the options in the block config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to select the new template on backend/layouts/blocks please add file to:

```
design/themes/[THEME_NAME]/templates/addons/[ADDON_NAME]/blocks/categories/[FILENAME].tpl
```

If you don't have a custom add-on already you can use My Changes add-on

```
design/themes/[THEME_NAME]/templates/addons/my_changes/blocks/categories/[FILENAME].tpl
```

PS: if category structure is missing you will need to create also you need to have My Changes add-on activated

Comment: I have added my new file to this location, but it's not appearing in the list. Do I need to declare it somewhere?

Comment: Works now, I found out I needed to activate the my_changes add-on in the admin. Do you know how to do the same thing for the product filter block? I put my file in `my_changes\blocks\product_filters\` but this one is not showing in the list...